# set bitmap in the center of screen in span

Tags: java, android

I am trying to put the bitmap in the center of my layout (Center-horizontal) but my bitmap always starts with the left and not centered. I assign the x value to setbound which center my image but shrink it rather the maintaining the ratio I selected.

[image][image]

```
private void setImageinText(Bitmap myBitmap){
    myBitmap = Util.scaleBitmapToFitWidth(myBitmap, 1360, true);
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), myBitmap);
    Point outSize = new Point();
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getSize(outSize);
    int[] widthAndHeight = new int[2];
    widthAndHeight[0] = outSize.x;
    int x = (widthAndHeight[0]- d.getIntrinsicWidth())/2;
    SpannableString ssd = new SpannableString("\n  \n");
    d.setBounds(x, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
    ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
    ssd.setSpan(span, 1 , 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    texto.setTransformationMethod(null);
    texto.getText().insert(texto.getSelectionStart(), ssd);
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan

Answer (score -1):

take ImageView below TextView and set it Centerhorizontal with Visibility GONE, then when you capture image set it in that ImageView and VISIBLE it.

Comment: I am creating imageview and bitmap programatically and want to place it any where inside the multitext lines.